# how to select specific columns from a data table in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable, datarow

I have a data table from which i am filtering data based on condition,but how to display specific columns only from the data table?

```
Dim Dt As New DataTable
                Dim SQlDa As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd)
                SQlDa.Fill(TrackingDt)
                Dim Rows() As DataRow = Dt.Select("State = " + "'" + State + "'")
                Dim TempDt As New DataTable
                If Rows.Length > -1 Then
                    TempDt = Rows.CopyToDataTable()
                End If


                Return TempDt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim view As New DataView(MyDataTable)
Dim distinctValues As DataTable = view.ToTable(True, "ColumnA")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like This

```
TempDt =New DataView(Rows.CopyToDataTable()).ToTable(False, 
"columnname1", "name2","...","..")
```

Comment: If i want to select multiple columns and filter distinct by a specific column, how should i do it?